# makefile PHONY can not link target

Tags: android, makefile, gnu-make

I use `.PHONY` in android makefile,but when i use "make xx",it can not link "xx",how cause this?
here is my code

```
.PHONY: test                                                           
test: $(compatibility) vtslab adb  echoTEST                                             
    $(call dist-for-goals,test,$(compatibility))      
echoTEST:                                                  
    @echo "2222"
```

why I can not use a `make test`?
it builds with error `unknown target 'test'`,

Comment: Could you provide your whole `Makefile`?

Comment: i build my makefile like "vts"

Comment: hello, i provide my "make file" alreadly,i wish your help

Comment: Equally important is what kind of error and error messages you are experiencing. Please add this too. Note that the question editor has a `{}` button to turn the typeset of marked text into fixed-font console-like output which is best for language syntax.

Comment: You'll need more details.  The makefile you posted above would build test, so you're missing something.   Try doing `cat Makefile && make --version && make -f Makefile test`, and paste the full output.   (My bet is that you're not running the Makefile you think you are)